# Java - BubbleSort - Is there a way for me to have the same input multiple times?

Tags: java, hashmap, bubble-sort

I'm trying to sort cards by their value using BubbleSort, but have got some problems when using the same card or a card with a similar value.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class KartenSort {

private int zwei = 2;
private int drei = 3;
private int vier = 4;
private int fuenf = 5;
private int sechs = 6;
private int sieben = 7;
private int acht = 8;
private int neun = 9;
private int zehn = 10;
private int koenig = 10;
private int dame = 10;
private int bube = 10;
private int ass = 11;

public int[] liste ={drei,zwei,fuenf,vier,koenig,sieben,ass};
public int[] sortieren(){

    int unsortiert;
    for(int sortiert = 0; sortiert < liste.length -1; sortiert++){

        if(liste[sortiert] <= liste[sortiert+1]){
            continue;
        }

    unsortiert = liste[sortiert];
        liste[sortiert] = liste[sortiert+1];
        liste[sortiert+1] = unsortiert;
        sortieren();
    }
return  liste;
}

public static void  main (String[] args){

    HashMap<Integer,String> numbers = new HashMap<>();
    numbers.put(2, "zwei");
    numbers.put(3, "drei");
    numbers.put(4, "vier");
    numbers.put(5, "fuenf");
    numbers.put(6, "sechs");
    numbers.put(7, "sieben");
    numbers.put(8, "acht");
    numbers.put(9, "neun");
    numbers.put(10, "zehn");
    numbers.put(10, "koenig");
    numbers.put(10, "dame");
    numbers.put(10, "bube");
    numbers.put(11, "ass");

    KartenSort bs = new KartenSort();
    int[] array = bs.sortieren();
    for (int sortiert=0;sortiert < array.length; sortiert++){
        System.out.println(numbers.get(array[sortiert]));
    }

}

}
```

Instead of it printing out "koenig", "dame", etc... all cards with the value 10 will show as "bube". Is there maybe a way to map them?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related with having the same values or anything. Your method `sortieren()` simply calls itself recursively without any base condition. This is the usual cause of a `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: but it does work when im not using the same values multiple times, it only happens when i do use the same values.

Comment: Ah, yes, because your condition is `<` rather than `<=`. Then it doesn't consider the list ever sorted. In any case, you shouldn't have a recursive call there.

Comment: altough that did work, it will now print both `koenig` and `dame` out as `bube`, so is there a way for me to mark them as `koenig`, etc...

Comment: You should use enums. Please read about them. The number is going to be one of the enum's internal fields.

Comment: ok, i'll look into that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statements:-

```
if(liste[sortiert] < liste[sortiert+1]){
  continue;
}
```

When both operands same value it will be evaluated to `false`. End up recursive `sortieren()` calls without array index increase. Change to `<=` operator for `continue` statement to work. For example:-

```
if(liste[sortiert] <= liste[sortiert+1]){
  continue;
}
```

Comment: altough that did work, it will now print both `koenig` and `dame` out as `bube`